# Need to write a "thirsty.sh" script: BASH

Tags: linux, scripting

Okay I have all of the code and it's working. I am just having trouble with the `while loop`

```
#asking the user if they are "thirsty". 
echo "Are you thirsty?"


#creating thirsty variable
read thirsty


#if user answers 'no'/'No'/'NO'/'n'/'N'.
if [ "$thirsty" == "no" ] || [ "$thisrty" == "No" ] || [ "$thisrty" == "N" ] || [ "$thisrty" == "n" ] || [ "$thisrty" == "NO" ]; then
    echo "Okay, thank you for coming. Have a nice day."
    exit
fi

#if user answers 'yes'/'Yes'/'YES'/'y'/'Y'
while [ "$thirsty" != "yes" ]; do

    if [ "$thirsty" == "yes" ] || [ "$thisrty" == "Yes" ] || [ "$thisrty" == "YES" ] || [ "$thisrty" == "y" ] || [ "$thisrty" == "Y" ]; then
        echo "Okay, what would you like to drink?"
        echo "We have: water, beer, wine, and anything else you can think of."
        read drink
        if [ "$drink" == "water" ]; then
            echo "Clear crisp and refreshing"
        elif [ "$drink" == "beer" ]; then
            echo "Let me see some ID"
        elif [ "$drink" == "wine" ]; then
            echo "One box or two?"
        else 
            echo "Coming right up..."
    fi
fi

done
```

I need the while loop to start the script over if they do not answer with at one of the "yes'" or one of the "no's"...

Comment: This does not directly answer your question, but you may find reading the bash documentation on `case` and `select` relevant.

Comment: Follow through the code process by hand. 1. You ask the question 2. You `read` an answer 3. You enter a `while` loop. Now you need to ask yourself, at what point in your while loop does the answer change?

Comment: typo: sometimes you use `$thirsty`, sometimes you use `$thisrty`

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I can see is that there are multiple typos with the word "thirsty" in your script, and that is preventing it to work properly. Search&Replace for the word "thisrty" for the correct word "thirsty".

---

Also, I'm not sure if you want to add more stuff to your code later on, but the way it is now, you could just replace your while for an infine loop and remove the "if" that is following right after the while, because the variable "thirsty" will never have its value changed again, like this:

```
#asking the user if they are "thirsty". 
echo "Are you thirsty?"
#creating thirsty variable
read thirsty
#if user answers 'no'/'No'/'NO'/'n'/'N'.
if [ "$thirsty" == "no" ] || [ "$thirsty" == "No" ] || [ "$thirsty" == "N" ] || [ "$thirsty" == "n" ] || [ "$thirsty" == "NO" ]; then
    echo "Okay, thank you for coming. Have a nice day."
    exit
fi

while [ 1 ]; do
    echo "Okay, what would you like to drink?"
    echo "We have: water, beer, wine, and anything else you can think of."
    read drink
    if [ "$drink" == "water" ]; then
        echo "Clear crisp and refreshing"
    elif [ "$drink" == "beer" ]; then
        echo "Let me see some ID"
    elif [ "$drink" == "wine" ]; then
        echo "One box or two?"
    else 
        echo "Coming right up..."
    fi
done
```

Comment: Good catch.... I copied and pasted the same code.... Thank you. But it was working at that point. It still works even with the while loop in there. I just want the while loop to start it over if they don't answer with Yes or No (or one of the variations.)

Answer (score 1):

You could change your code to use a function to prompt for user's (player's?) input.

```
is_thirsty() {
  echo """
  Are you thirsty (Yes/No)?'
  """
  while :
  do
    read -p '>' thirsty
    case ${thirsty^^} in
      NO|N)
        return 1
        ;;
      YES|Y)
        return 0
        ;;
      *)
        echo -n '(Yes/No)'
        ;;
    esac
  done
}
```

This is an example usage:

```
choose_drink() {
  echo """
  Okay, what would you like to drink?
  We have: water, beer, wine and anything else you can think of.
  """
  read -p '>' drink
  case ${drink^^} in
    WATER)
      echo "Clear crisp and refreshing"
      ;;
    BEER)
      echo "Let me see some ID"
      ;;
    WINE)
      echo "One box or two?"
      ;;
    *)
      echo "Coming right up..."
      ;;
  esac
}

goodbye() {
  echo "Okay, thank you for coming. Have a nice day."
}

is_thirsty && choose_drink || goodbye
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this

```
# Make thirsty an uppercase variable
typeset -u thirsty

# Initialize thirsty
thirsty="INIT"

while [ "$thirsty" != "YES" || "$thirsty" != "Y" || "$thirsty" != "NO" || "$thirsty" != "N" ]
do

#asking the user if they are "thirsty". 
    echo "Are you thirsty?"


#creating thirsty variable
    read thirsty


#if user answers 'no'/'No'/'NO'/'n'/'N'.
    if [ "$thirsty" == "NO" ] || [ "$thisrty" == "N" ]; then
        echo "Okay, thank you for coming. Have a nice day."
        exit
    fi

#if user answers 'yes'/'Yes'/'YES'/'y'/'Y'
    while [ "$thirsty" != "YES" ]; do

        if [ "$thirsty" == "YES" ] || [ "$thisrty" == "Y" ]; then
            echo "Okay, what would you like to drink?"
            echo "We have: water, beer, wine, and anything else you can think of."
            read drink
            if [ "$drink" == "water" ]; then
                echo "Clear crisp and refreshing"
            elif [ "$drink" == "beer" ]; then
                echo "Let me see some ID"
            elif [ "$drink" == "wine" ]; then
                echo "One box or two?"
            else 
                echo "Coming right up..."
            fi
        fi

    done
done
```

Give it a try and tell me what you think.